# Ensuring cell height adjusts per custom UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift2

I have defined a custom UITableViewCell, used in UITableViewController, which is displaying in my table. The issue is the cell is retaining the original height, as the default UITableViewCell, instead of using the height I specified in the "Size inspector" -> "table view cell" -> "row height".

My custom cell is loaded as follows:

```
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

and then in the tableView function:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
cell.titleLabel?.text = "title text"
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "detail text to go here"
```

I had tried manually setting the height as follows, but this does not work either:

```
cell.frame.size.height = 100.0
```

Any ideas of the right way to have the cell at the right height?

XCode 7.2.1, iOS 9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your tableview cell data is static and have same height for every cells, override this function (if you using `UITableViewController` subclass) to return the height of your cell.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100.0
}
```

Else, if your data is dynamic and you want each cell to have their own height, set this in `viewDidLoad` method:

```
   tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
   tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Don't forget to apply constraint for all views (such `UILabel`, `UIImageView`, etc) in your cell to let the `tableView` automatically calculate and resize the cell height.

Answer (score 0):

Row height is a property of the *table*. In your table view controller's `viewDidLoad`, probably right where you already say this:

```
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

also say this:

```
tableView.rowHeight = 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
TableView.estimatedRowHeight
```

To something meaningful

Make sure your constraints allow for correct sizing. This is the most important part. If you cannot, there are a few more ways. But you don't want to go there. This is by far the most convenient approach

Do not use rowHeight or the related delegate/data source function

Answer (score 0):

In Obj C, you can implement this function in a `UITableViewController` subclass:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 100; // or whatever your cell height is
}
```

maybe there is an equivalent in Swift